# Xamarin C# error : Unexpected Symbol

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to code a slider on Xamarin using C#. I am getting an error

> Unexpected symbol 'var'

for the first line of code after all the namespaces (the line starting with "var page"). If anyone could help me out with this, that would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

var page = new ContentPage ();

var header = new Label {
    Text = "Slider",
    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
    FontSize = 50,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};

var slider = new Slider {
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 100,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
};

slider.ValueChanged += 
    (sender, e) => {String.Format ("Slider value is {0:F1}", e.NewValue);};

label = new Label {
    Text = "Slider value is 0",
    FontSize = 25,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};

page.Padding = new Thickness (10, Device.OnPlatform (20, 0, 0), 10, 5);

page.Content = new StackLayout {
    Children = {
        header,
        slider,
        label
    }
};
```

Comment: I think you really need to start with the basics here. Your executable code isn't inside a class, let alone a method.

Comment: As @DavidG pointed out, your code needs to be in a class.   Methods, properties and members go in the class, assignments go in methods and properties.

Comment: and class fields cannot be `var`

Answer (score 1):

If this is your entire source file, you haven't defined a `class` anywhere. Variable definitions must be contained inside of a `class`. Once you define a class, you'll have to have a method for this executable code to be defined in.